# Create a measure that takes the average based on the results of count distinct from a long table?

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have a dataset in power bi that looks like this

```
ID1|ID2
123 456
123 456 
456 123
890 123
890 123
123 890
123 890
456 123
456 123
123 456
```

The table I created shows

```
ID 1 Count Distinct 
123   2
456   1
890   1
```

I want to average based on the values of the count column. Note that ID 123 is associated with two other ID's at 456 and 890. 456 and 890 are associated with an other id just once. I want the average based on what is shown on the page at the moment.

2+1+1 which is 4/3 at 1.33

I did find this and it almost does the trick

```
AVERAGEX (
VALUES ( TABLE[ID1]),
CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( TABLE ) )
)
```

However what this does instead it takes the average of

```
ID 1 Count 
123  5 
456  3
890  3
```

I want the average of count distinct instead

```
    AVERAGEX (
VALUES ( DISTINCT(TABLE[ID1])),
CALCULATE ( DISTINCT(COUNTROWS ( TABLE )) )
)
```

Comment: There are 2nd level of parent/child relation. Is this true for your real data? or there may be level 3 or 4 or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

```
Average Attendees Per Day = 
AVERAGEX (
VALUES ( TABLE[ID1]),
CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[ID2] ))
)
```